# How to put iron golem farm away from other beds and workstations

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I built silentwisperer's [Upgradeable Iron Farm](https://youtu.be/3BhlLIIpRh4) in my realm but it didn’t work. I realised that others in the realm may have left beds and workstations underground nearby and wondered if that might be affecting it?  In order to get 96 or 125 or whatever blocks from the nearest beds and workstations, can I just build it high up?

Comment: I can’t watch the video - it’s restricted for me - but if the iron farm involves water than no you cannot build it higher up. The water source will freeze provided it is higher than 90 y coordinate.

Comment: I looked into this. It depends on the biome. Fortunately, I’m not in one where water freezes at that height. But thanks for the warning: I hadn’t even considered that.

Answer (score 2):

That iron farm design is very finicky (though it's sadly still one of the better designs). When it's not working it tends to be for these reasons:

1. A villager cannot reach its workstation.
2. There is an extra villager somewhere not linked to a bed.
3. A villager linked to some other bed outside the farm, causing your center of the village not to be where needed.

Golems will spawn, but not where they need to, if the problem is #3, so if by "not working" you mean no golems  are spawning, then the problem is #1 or #2.

For a golem to spawn, *all* villagers need to be linked to beds and there need to be enough villagers working at  workstations they can reach. What I recommend is that you break all the workstations and beds to start over. Place all the beds and make sure you can observe the green sparkles for each bed placed. For good measure, place an extra bed and make sure no green sparkles appear. If they do, that means there was an unlinked villager. Keep placing beds until there are no green sparkles. Then you need to be absolutely certain the workstation you placed linked to a villager in the respective pod. You can see who would link to the next placed workstation by putting it down randomly somewhere and observing which villager pod had a villager with green sparkles. You must then break and place that workstation at *that* pod.

You should not have to build too high up.

Comment: I didn’t get any golems anywhere so it must’ve been #1 or #2. I’m building in a realm and I couldn’t guarantee that someone wouldn’t accidentally put a bed or workstation somewhere nearby so I moved it up into the sky around 200. Initially, it didn’t work.  I added a 21st bed and later opened up the block above the villagers (so they were in a 1x1x3high space and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I watched the video and I don’t see why not - though it would be much more difficult to build and get your villagers up there.

Comment: It did take a rather high villager elevator tower but they’re up there now and I have golems! I turned the village elevator into a soul sand elevator for me so it wasn’t a wasted effort.